# Stop user being able to access live CD environment or recovery mode?

Tags: security, boot

I'm haved created an account on ubuntu that is just a standard user but with no internet access. I have also removed 'recovery mode' from the grub menu so that one cannot just choose this option access root and reverse all my changes (maybe a safer option could have been passwording this rather than removing...), but this still leaves the option of simply booting into the liveCD/USB and being able to access the internet etc...

Is there a way to prevent a user being able to boot into liveCD environment?

Comment: If network access is the core issue, you could consider just removing the network card. You can always plug in a usb network interface to do updates etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this in 2 steps,

1. Set a password for grub, so one can't modify boot entry
2. Lock down BIOS with a password, disable external media boot

Optionally, you could encrypt the root volume, so even booted from another media, one can find it hard to modify settings

Answer (score 2):

Set the options in the BIOS to disallow booting from external media and password lock BIOS access so the user can't re-enable it.

Answer (score 2):

What bahamat said.  But keep in mind that if someone has physical access to a host, they can pretty much do whatever they want.  BIOS settings can be overridden by pulling the cmos battery, for instance.